# Integrate fails for generic parameters but works for any specific values (v. 10.0.x bug)

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, bugs

**Bug introduced in 9.0 and fixed in 10.1**

---

I was trying to get the following integral

```
Integrate[Sqrt[y/x] (Sin[t]^2 Cos[t])/(x+y+2 Sqrt[x y] Cos[t]), {t,0,Pi}, 
Assumptions -> {x > 0, y > 0, x > y}]
```

Mathematica answers

```
RFalse[x_,y_]=Pi(1/(8y)-(3y)/(8x^2))
```

This is wrong as the result is

```
RTrue[x_,y_]=-(Pi y)/(4x^2)
```

However, if one gives definite value for the parameters Mathematica calculates the integral correctly. Running

```
x1 = RandomReal[{10, 20}];
y1 = RandomReal[10];
Chop[Integrate[Sqrt[y1/x1] (Sin[t]^2 Cos[t])/(x1+y1+2 Sqrt[x1 y1] Cos[t]), 
{t,0,Pi}]-RTrue[x1,y1]]==0
```

returns True, while

```
Chop[Integrate[Sqrt[y1/x1] (Sin[t]^2 Cos[t])/(x1+y1+2 Sqrt[x1 y1] Cos[t]), 
{t,0,Pi}]-RFalse[x1,y1]]==0
```

returns False.

Many integrals of this type do not give the correct answer.

Any idea?

Comment: What do you mean by `Mathematica answers RFalse[x_,y_]=Pi(1/(8y)-(3y)/(8x^2))`? That's  quite a strange answer!

Comment: Also, just in case, your `Integrate[ ]` has a syntax error. I'm downvoting until you correct it

Comment: After correcting your integration expression to `Integrate[Sqrt[y/x] (Sin[t]^2 Cos[t])/(x + y + 2 Sqrt[x y] Cos[t]), {t, 0, Pi}, Assumptions ->{x > 0, y > 0, x > y}]` with `version 10.1` I get the expected `-((Pi*y)/(4*x^2))`

Comment: @BobHanlon I posted that as an answer a few seconds after your comment. Deleting

Comment: I have corrected the typo, sorry about that. 
As for RFalse and RTrue I just typed that way in view of the later test I decided to make. Mathematica just gives  Pi(1/(8y)-(3y)/(8x^2)), and I turned it into a function of the parameters x and y. 
And my version of Mathematica 10.0.1.0 on my Mac gives me the result I quoted not the correct result.

Comment: Mathematica 10.0.1 win7x64 returns the result `Pi(1/(8 y)-3 y/(8 x^2))` on my machine.

Comment: However, after some transformations `Integrate[(Sin[t] Sin[2 t]/2)/(a + 2 b Cos[t]), {t, 0, Pi}, 
 Assumptions -> {a > 2 b, b > 0}]` returns something different, and after some replacements (`a->x+y`, `b->Sqrt[x y]`), multiplications by `Sqrt[y/x]`, then `PowerExpand@%; Simplify@%` the correct result *is* obtained.

Comment: I don't think this question should be closed. The OP has found a real bug in V10.0.x,

Answer (score 5):

```
$Version
```

> "10.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (September 10, 2014)"

As entered Mathematica returns the wrong result.

```
Integrate[Sqrt[y/x] (Sin[t]^2 Cos[t])/(x + y + 2 Sqrt[x y] Cos[t]), {t, 0, 
  Pi}, Assumptions -> {x > 0, y > 0, x > y}]
```

> Pi*(1/(8*y) - (3*y)/(8*x^2))

However, a workaround is to convert the trig functions to exponentials

```
Integrate[Sqrt[y/x] (Sin[t]^2 Cos[t])/(x + y + 2 Sqrt[x y] Cos[t]) // 
  TrigToExp, {t, 0, Pi}, Assumptions -> {x > 0, y > 0, x > y}]
```

> -((Pi*y)/(4*x^2))

Comment: So is this a bug?

Comment: @LLlAMnYP - Looks like one to me, but I never studied entomology.

Comment: Thank you for confirming this and for the workaround.

Answer (score 3):

This appears to be a bug in V10.0.x which was fixed in V10.1.0.

```
$Version
```

> ```
> "10.1.0  for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (March 24, 2015)"
> ```

```
Integrate[Sqrt[y/x] (Sin[t]^2 Cos[t])/(x + y + 2 Sqrt[x y] Cos[t]), {t, 0, Pi},
  Assumptions -> {x > 0, y > 0, x > y}]
```

> ```
> -((π y)/(4 x^2))
> ```

Comment: Also version 8 for the Mac was free of the bug.